# javascript, dynamic id for table:how to recognize?

Tags: javascript

In my application i use a framework that generates a table with the id of the cells at Run-Time in ascending order.
So that i have "ElementX1X1" for row1 and column1, "ElementX1X2" for row1 and column2 etcetc...
The HTML structure generated will be:

```
<tr>
<td class="my_msg" align="left">
<id="ElementX1X1">
```

what i can set is the class(my_msg) and the content of the cell(of the table).
I want simply make:

```
var test=document.getElementById("ElementX1X1");
test.onclick=function();
```

but i'm not able to recognize the cell... 
i want to make getElementById only if it is in the class "my_msg" or only if it has a certain content(as i said the only two things i can set)...
Anyone has any idea on how i can solve the problem?!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *The HTML structure generated will be* … invalid.

Comment: Use getElementsByTagName to get all tds and check className / innerHTML for each one

Comment: Please fix your HTML first; you probably meant to write `<td id="ElementX1X1" class="my_msg" align="left">`.

Comment: "check className / innerHTML for each one" could you explain it better please?!?
No, the HTML generated is as i have written...it's generated by a framework...

Comment: @CaptainAmerica. Hey captain, doesn't my answer help you with it?

Answer (score 2):

Update the HTML to:
<td id="ElementX1X1" class="my_msg" >...

Edited - to work around broken framework:

```
<tr>
  <td class="my_msg" align="left">
   <id="ElementX1X1">
   some content
  </td>
  <td class="my_msg" align="left">
   <id="ElementX1X2">
   some content
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you want to find row 1 column 2, you can cheat using a bit of jQuery to inspect the contents of the element:

```
var row = 1; 
var column = 2;
var matched = null;
$(".my_msg").each({ 
    if($(this).html().indexOf('<id="ElementX' + row + 'X' + column + '">')!=-1){ 
        matched = $(this);
    } 
});
```

matched will either point to the element you're looking for or null - but if you already know the row and column id's of the cells then why not just walk the DOM?

```
var row = 1; 
var column = 2;
var matched = null;
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0]; // up to you how your find it
try {
    matched = table.getElementsByTagName("TR")[row-1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[column-1];
} 
catch(err) { 
    // not found
}
```

Or the brute force way (i.e. fix the framework output):

```
var table = $("#tableid");  // up to you how your find it
table.html(table.html().replace(/">\n<id="/g,'" id="'));
```

your code is now:

```
<tr>
    <td class="my_msg" align="left" id="ElementX1X1">…</td>
    <td class="my_msg" align="left" id="ElementX1X2">…</td>
…
```

so you can use

```
$("#ElementX2X1");
```

to select the first row, second column

Neither is particularly elegant, but should get the job done while you wait for your buggy framework to be fixed ;)

Comment: He's asking how he can get the element without the id. it's done with a framework.

Comment: Fix the framework - that's malformed XML - it's not even valid HTML